# Mustache templating Objects

Tags: javascript, mustache

I want to use mustache to template some data.
The data to template is like :

```
var data = {
            "lib" : "L1",
            "group" : 
               {"echelle" : "Bassin"}
           }
```

I try to use mustache :

```
var templateResult = "<tr><td><p>{{lib}}</p></td><td><p>{{>group}}</p></td></tr>";
var partials = {"group" : "{{#group}}<td><p>{{echelle}}</p></td>{{/group}}"}

$("#result_indic_table").append(Mustache.render(templateResult, data, partials));
```

And it just doesn't work... What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem...
the data wasn't like I thought :

```
data = {
            "indicateur" : {
              "lib" : "L1",
              "group" : 
                 {"echelle" : "Bassin"}
            }
        }
```

So the template should look like :

```
var templateResult = "{{#indicateur}}<tr><td><p>{{lib}}</p></td><td><p>{{>group}}</p></td></tr>{{/indicateur}}";
var partials = {"group" : "{{#group}}<td><p>{{echelle}}</p></td>{{/group}}"}
```

And it's done.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with mustachejs is being what it is. I'd rather go for `Swig` or `Dust.js`